# open binary file of 16 bit integers written by a c program as 1s and 0s in python

Tags: python, binary, short

I have a bitstream file that is comprised of several lines. The c program executable that produces the file outputs the file as a series of "short int" which are actually 16 bit integers. When I open the file in notepad I get the following first few lines:

```
7E1755EB7909DAC8FF4117BDAA0E86EBD1A8
1C3D47DD6606D812E8862D347288C3A251EB
16D7D02AD908E0083C142C107AB916C55BE0
```

I need to be able to open this file in Python and convert it to 1s and 0s that represent the original "short int" or in other words an array of 1s and 0s. I think I might also have an issue with the "\n" meaning new line when I read in the file.

I've tried the following code to see which method works best:

```
import struct

filePathC = "C:\\Working\\Vocoder Sims\\ofile.chan"

fileC = open(filePathC, "rb")

with fileC:

    byteC = fileC.read(8)

    binaryC1 = bin(int(byteC,16))
    binaryC2 = struct.unpack("h" * (len(byteC)/2),byteC)

    print binaryC1
    print binaryC2
```

The result for when I only read in the first 8 bytes is:

```
0b1111110000101110101010111101011
(17719, 14129, 13621, 16965)
```

The issue with the first result is that I should be getting 64 1s and 0s and the problem with the second is that it "tuple" instead of an array of 1s and 0s and I don't believe the integers are 16 bit based. They look more like 15 bit but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That is **not** a binary file. It is a hex file.

Comment: How can you tell? Couldn't notepad just be interpreting it as HEX?

Comment: If this was a random binary file, notepad would show junk. There is a small chance that the binary just happens to look like an ascii hex encoding but that's not very likely. Your commentary mentioning lines is also a hint. There are no lines in binary data because, unlike a text file, the newline byte (or bytes on windows) is just more random binary data.

Comment: The issue I have with your explanation that this is HEX is that I went into the c-code that the executable was compiled from and produces the file and it is clearly defined as a "short int" and the file is written that way.

Comment: How was the file written? If it was some version of `fprintf` using a format string like `"%04x"`, then you wrote ascii text.

Comment: "fwrite" was used.

Comment: Your second example is "correct" in that you built a tuple of integers. The tuple is an "array" of sorts (ie, binaryC2[2] gets the third value) and even though they display as integers, they are the binary values. Python has an `array` and I'll post an example solution with that, but its still going to decode the file like your second example. It would be interesting to do `print repr(open(filePathC, 'rb').read(2))` so we can make sure the file is the binary data you want.

Comment: That's great! `'7E'`, is `17719` decimal, `0x4537` hex, or `0b100010100110111` binary. Your second example gave you the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have binary data that just happens to decode as ascii hex, you could read the file into a python `array`. Its not much different than your second example of unpacking into a tuple except that its faster and has a lower memory footprint. Depending on what you want to do next, it would be reasonable to read into a `numpy` array instead.

```
import os
import array

#filePathC = "C:\\Working\\Vocoder Sims\\ofile.chan"
filePathC = "test.bin"

count = os.stat(filePathC).st_size / 2
with open(filePathC, 'rb') as fp:
    binaryC3 = array.array("h")
    binaryC3.fromfile(fp, count)

print binaryC3
print bin(binaryC3[0])
```

For your example file, this gave me

```
array('h', [17719, 14129, 13621, 16965, 14647, 14640, 16708, 14403, 17990, 12596, 14129, 17474, 16705, 17712, 13880, 16965, 12612, 14401, 12554, 13123, 13380, 17463, 13892, 12342, 17462, 12600, 17714, 14392, 12854, 13124, 14132, 14386, 17208, 16691, 13618, 17713, 2626, 13873, 14148, 12356, 16690, 14660, 14384, 12357, 14384, 17203, 13361, 17202, 12337, 16695, 14658, 13873, 13635, 16949, 12357])
0b100010100110111
```

Comment: How do I convert this array into 1s and 0s that I can perform modulo 2 operation on?

Comment: You want one single long stream of 0's and 1s? I thought you wanted an array of short 16 bit values. Let me think about that...

Comment: Yes. I want to add bit errors and then put the file back together again in the same format. That's really the end game. I want to take the origianl bitstream file and errors.